# Can a new participant be added onto a multisisg 2/3 scheme?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, multisig

Once a multisig wallet is created with a specific scheme, can a new participant be added, or does a new multisig wallet need to be made? 
The same question for if a participant can be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once the wallet has been finalized, you cannot change the participants. Should you need to add a new participant, you would need to create a new wallet with the old and new participants then transfer funds from the old multisig wallet to the new one.